# configuring smtp settings

Tags: asp.net

Hello i am trying to configure my smtp so that when users create an account, their username and password should be sent directly to their email address. I am stuch in this section in the web.config file.
Server Name, Server port, From. Is the server name the name of the company server thats hosting my website?
2) Is the server port the port number of the company thats hosting my website? eg godaddy?
3)The From is the email address i created from my hosting account? I will appreciate help from u guys.
Thank u

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot send email in ASP.NET through Godaddy servers.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360214/cannot-send-email-in-asp-net-through-godaddy-servers)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the configuration that I use to send email on my shared hosting account with godaddy.

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2009/08/send-email-programmatically-on-godaddy/

Hope this helps.

Bob

Comment: This make alot of sense but my question is, were should i put it? In the web.conf file?

Comment: For my blog, I left all the configuration in line. Maybe not the best design, but I don't reconfigure my email often (never have).