# configuration of asp.net mailmessage

Tags: asp.net

Can someone help me pls. I am ready to deploy my web application. I have a contact form that i want users to send me a message. Ive created the smtp when i click on submit, i get the error message cannot be sent.
 The application is still on my local machine maybe thats why. But i just want to know if this code is good for my form:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail


Partial Class contact
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(ByVal source As Object, ByVal args As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles CustomValidator1.ServerValidate
        If txtComments.Text.Length > 300 Then
            args.IsValid = False
        Else
            args.IsValid = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Wizard1_FinishButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.WizardNavigationEventArgs) Handles Wizard1.FinishButtonClick
        SendMail(txtEmail.Text, txtComments.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub SendMail(ByVal from As String, ByVal body As String)
        Dim mailServerName As String = "SMTP.relay-hosting.secureserver.net"
        Dim message As MailMessage = New MailMessage(from, "collins@collinsegbe.com", "feedback", body)
        Dim mailClient As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient

        mailClient.Host = mailServerName
        mailClient.Send(message)
        message.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The error is indicated on this line of code: mailClient.Send(message)
I will appreciate help from anyone

Comment: The error message from the exception or any inner exceptions should contain the source of the problem. What are they?

Comment: Check your settings using telnet to validate that they are working first. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995718%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx

Comment: Isn't the host just 'relay-hosting@secureserver.net'? Also be certain that the from domain is the domain of the site. Continuation of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356076/configuring-smtp-settings/4356135#4356135

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void Button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        var fromAddress = new MailAddress("rusty109.stud@gmail.com");
        var toAddress = new MailAddress(TextBox13.Text);
        const string fromPassword = "commando1";
        string subject = TextBox14.Text;
        string body = TextBox12.Text;

        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword),
            Timeout = 20000
        };
        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body
        })
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
    }
}
```

my old code when i wanted to email, you can use the gmail account if you wish, nothing in it... was set up to  use this code :) 
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the username and password for the SMTP server by setting the `SmtpClient`'s `Credential` property to an instance of the `NetworkCredential` class.

Comment: godaddy told me they don't ask for username and password.

Comment: This might be configured in the config file.

Comment: @onfire: I find that highly unlikely.