# Contact us section

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having problems with my asp.net application i can run the program with no errors when i fill in the boxes on the contact us section i then get a error saying.

> SMTPException was unhanded by user code

Here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


public partial class contactUs : System.Web.UI.Page
{
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void submitform(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MailMessage email = new MailMessage()
            {
                Subject = "Email From CraigavonAquatics Contact Us Section",
                Body = commentBox.Text,
                IsBodyHtml = false,
                From = new MailAddress(emailBox.Text, nameBox.Text)
            };
            email.To.Add(new MailAddress("craigavonaquatics@gmail.com", "Philip Harrison"));

            SmtpClient server = new SmtpClient();
            server.Send(email);
            msgSuccess.Visible = true;

        }
```

Comment: Post the full error message exactly as you see it. Also, if you're hosted talk with your host asking what is their SMTP server and what user/password you need for it. By default Smtpclient try to send from `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: i am trying to send the email to a simple gmail.com web address

Comment: can you show us your stmp configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your code in a try catch block. Then, check any inner exceptions.

For example:

```
try{

...
...
}
catch( Exception ex )
{
 Exeception e = ex;
      while( e != null ){
       Response.Write (e.ToString());
       Response.Write("<HR>");
       e = e.InnerException;
      }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying any smtp server to use!

Comment: i have tho in web.config file

Answer (score 0):

Many hosting companies do not allow out bound emails that originate from a domain that is not yours. So emails sent from your page at x.com must be from someone like y@x.com.

Add a try catch in there to gather more info.

Bob

Here is a similar discussion: [Issue sending mail message from ASP.NET MVC application hosted on GoDaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444342/issue-sending-mail-message-from-asp-net-mvc-application-hosted-on-godaddy)